# Open windows taskbar when browser minimized

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a MVC Web Application for time tracking system. In this if the browser window minimized , then the informations like daily target and completed target of the particular user are needs to display in windows taskbar...

How can I achieve this..
Plz help..

Thanks
Magesh.M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 notification API. Take a look at this, for example:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/

This mechanism allows a webpage to make use of the OS notification system like the popup bubbles near the windows clock.